# document.getElementsByName returns more elements than expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a RadioButtonList

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist runat="server" id="rblList">
    <asp:listitem>s1</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem>s2</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem>s3</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem>s4</asp:listitem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

In my client code I'm grabbing the array of radio buttons like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("rblList");
```

Why am I getting 5 items instead of 4?  It makes `elements` like a 1 based array.

Comment: Did you look at the values in your array?

Comment: kind of, I added some javascript to peek in there.  My answer below has the details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the RadioButtonList produces the following HTML

```
<table id="rblList" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rblList_0" type="radio" name="rblList" value="s1" /><label for="rblList_0">s1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rblList_1" type="radio" name="rblList" value="s2" /><label for="rblList_1">s2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rblList_2" type="radio" name="rblList" value="s3" /><label for="rblList_2">s3</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rblList_3" type="radio" name="rblList" value="s4" /><label for="rblList_3">s4</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

According to MSDN I'm getting 5 elements because I'm getting the radio buttons AND the table that ASP.Net it putting them in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28VS.85%29.aspx

> *When you use the getElementsByName method, all elements in the document
>   that have the specified NAME attribute
>   or ID attribute value are returned.*

So, putting this bit of javaScript on the page:

```
function showEle() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("rblList");

    alert("elements length=" + elements.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        try {
            alert("elements[" + i + "]" + ", id=" + elements[i].id + ", name=" + elements[i].name + ", value = " + elements[i].value);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert("error reading elements[" + i + "].value");
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to see this...

elements[0], id=rblList, name=undefined, value = undefined
elements[1], id=rblList_0, name=rblList, value = s1
elements[2], id=rblList_1, name=rblList, value = s2
elements[3], id=rblList_2, name=rblList, value = s3
elements[4], id=rblList_3, name=rblList, value = s4

`element[0]` is the table, the others are the radio buttons

Comment: This applies to IE.  FF doesn't have this "feature".

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you have another element on the page with the name `rblList`. Using the following test:

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>S1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>S2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>S3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>S4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var foo = document.getElementsByName('<%=this.RadioButtonList1.UniqueID %>');
            alert(foo.length);
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

I get four elements.

Comment: What browser?  I found out that IE does getElementsByName() differently than other browsers.  So, that combined with how ASP.Net renders the RadioButtonList gave me 5.

Comment: @Homer - The browsers should all render the same. I checked IE7, IE8, FF 3.5, and Chrome 5 and they all show four elements.

Comment: hmm, the js alert shows me 5 elements in IE8, 4 elements in FF 3.6.  I think we might be talking about different things here.  It does render the same in all the browsers, but IE returns a different result for getElementsByName().

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the HTML created by the code (i.e. "view source"). It may be that the element does not have the **name** `rblList`, but rather the **id**. In that case, I recommend using `getElementsByID`.

Comment: since an ID should be unique, it is getElementByID (only one) :-)

Comment: It SHOULD be unique, but I (sadly) found out it doesn't have to be :). Obviously, if it's up to me, it is - but some people write forms relying wholly on name= and give all their dropdowns the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

you have a runat="server" in your code and many asp-tags... This means that your code example is server side code which will be replaced with html before sending to the client.

Check out yout html and you'll find the reason!

... and check for the "name" attribute... getElementsByName returns all elements with a specific "name" attribute. There can be several.

If you want to select by ID (unique) it is getElementByID (without the plural 's' of Elements).